# React + TypeScript - how to update state with single object with a "dynamic" set of changes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, setstate, tslint

I want to update the state at the end of a list of conditional updates and accumulates the changes to be committed at once (to avoid async issues with setState).

```
interface IMyComponentState {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}

(...)

updateState = (condition1: boolean, condition2: boolean) => {
    const stateChanges: Partial<IMyComponentState> = {};

    if (condition1) {
        stateChanges.a = 'someValue 1';
    }
    if (condition2) {
        stateChanges.b = 'someValue 2';
    }
    this.setState(
        { ...this.state, ...stateChanges },
        () => this.doSomethingThatDependsOnState()
    );
}
```

This works fine, but is there a way to do it without using `this.state`, like below?

```
    this.setState(
        {...stateChanges},
        (...)
    );
```

Here `tslint` is complaining that `setState` expects an object of type `Pick<IMyComponentState, "a" | "b" | "c">` but that would require me to specify (and predict) the properties to be changed in advance, which is not possible. I heard that React's diffing algorithm checks the references, but I'm still concerned that putting the whole `state` object in `setState` would add an extra overhead or is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to spread `this.state`, React will only apply state changes to the specified keys.

Secondly, the type for `setState` intentionally doesn't use `Partial<T>`, this is because setting `undefined` on a key *explicitly* will perform a state update, so it uses `Pick` ([GitHub issue here talking more about it](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26635))

To get around this issue, you can cast you state update to `Pick<IMyComponentState, keyof IMyComponentState>`;

```
updateState = (condition1: boolean, condition2: boolean) => {
  const stateChanges = {};

  if (condition1) {
    stateChanges.a = 'someValue 1';
  }
  if (condition2) {
    stateChanges.b = 'someValue 2';
  }
  this.setState(
    { ...stateChanges } as Pick<IMyComponentState, keyof IMyComponentState>,
    () => this.doSomethingThatDependsOnState()
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Re. spreading the `this.state` - that was the only way I could think of to have the required `Pick` type there (my `stateChanges` is `Partial`). (thanks for the link!)